# Django backend not returning JSON on production server, getting 404

Tags: python, json, django, nginx

I have a Django backend that returns json data. I'm able to get data back on my localhost but got a 404 on production server. I'm running nginx in front of gunicorn server. Any ideas why I'm getting a 404? Shouldn't this be able to work to retrieve json data, or do I need to use django rest framework and implement viewsets to make this work?

```
Not Found

The requested URL /about was not found on this server.
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^about', about.get_info),
]
```

about.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def get_info(req):
    return JsonResponse({"test": "hello"})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is inside `url.py`. The way the rules are defined currently, it would only allow you to open `about/` and `admin/`, i.e. with the `/` at the end. To fix this, you can define the URLs as following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/$', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^about/$', about.get_info),
]
```

Now you should be able to use both `admin/` and `admin` to access the page.

Comment: sorry added an extra /, it works when on dev but it doesn't work on production

Comment: Did you make sure that you refreshed the code base on the production server, and, if you're using WSGI, made the server aware that there is new code? Please look here for more detail: https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/wikis/ReloadingSourceCode.wiki

Comment: thanks, had to reload gunicorn server, any ideas why i would use DRF with viewsets over simply defining my API endpoints like this in my urls.py?

Comment: Using DRF comes with a lot of advantages like methods and templates that you can use. It helps with the formatting of headers, plugs nicely into the entire Django infrastructure. For example, you can use model view controllers to automatically form the API output based on your model data etc.